# How to deindex URLs which belong to your site but aren't listed in the WordPress "pages" section?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering how I could take out of the Google index any URL which is not listed in the "pages" section in WordPress but still belongs to my site.

As you may see in the attachment, a link to the "admin" page appears in the SERP snippet related to my website, which is very inconvenient! It is an internal "ghost" page which should not appear to potential customers...

The URL in question is https://www.myoutlet.lt/ru/author/admin/ but, as I said, it does not exist in the WordPress back-end, so I am quite clueless. I cannot just deindex it by means of Yoast or similar, because I can´t accede to the back-end of this page!

I suppose that I should add some code to the .htaccess file, but I have not found any viable solution so far.

SERP Snippet

[image: SERP Snippet]

Comment: That's not a "page" like other pages. That's an author page, which WP generates for all authors (users). If you're using WP to build a web site and not a blog, and don't want to show some author info for some users, you can disable author pages completely. Here's a post about it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277649/how-to-remove-the-author-pages

Answer (score 0):

This link shows how to disable author pages:
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/disable-enable-author-archives/

And

You can noindex the pages using a robots.txt file.

Robots are any type of “bot” that visits websites on the Internet. The most common example is search engine crawlers. These bots “crawl” around the web to help search engines like Google index and rank the billions of pages on the Internet.

You can create a `robots.txt` file using the `Yoast Plugin`
Steps Below:
Step 1:
[image: Step 1]

Step 2:
[image: Step 2]

Step 3:
[image: Step 3]

Now disallow the page you need to noindex:
Add this to your robots.txt file

`Disallow: /ru/author/admin/`

Comment: "You can noindex the pages using a robots.txt file" -> actually, this is a quite widespread misconception. "If you disallow a URL in robots.txt the search engines can’t crawl it. They *WILL* index it, as they can’t see the noindex tag on the page
If you want a page NOT indexed in the search results, then do NOT add it to the robots.txt file. Only add the meta noindex tag on the page." https://searchnewscentral.com/blog/2018/02/02/robots-txt-noindex-tag/